# How to filter out unwanted/official Twitter posts

Tags: twitter, filter, nlp, spam-prevention

I am now doing an NLP project which needs some resources from twitter.

I want to get those tweets posted by "real people" instead of any kind of "official accounts", including celebrities, ads, institutions, media, etc. such as @CNN @TodayWeather @obama @DailySale @BestPrice @FashionTrend.

Hence, is there a better way to do so?

I have considered about it for a long time. By using twitter's API, the returned JSON includes a key called "verified". This can be used to detect weather an account is that kind of "official account". However, today, this blue "V" tick is not only for those shining celebrities. Anyone can apply for it as long as they are a real person. So, I think using this solution will rule out a lot of precious resources.

Moreover, I also considered using textual spam filter. yeah, of course, they are quite good in most cases. However, some accounts, such as @FT, their posts never sound like a spammy ad. But it is not what I want.

I want to ask for a better solution. It can be a long term solution, such as using NLP and NeuroNets to learn from labels. But, well, a prompt solution will be very welcomed.

THX